# Generate preview/thumbnail of component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am currently storing an object containing many React components and would like to display them all in some sort of gallery format.

I tried rendering the component directly in the gallery itself, but it was too slow and caused too many DOM issues.

Similar to how Google Drive displays a preview of each doc, what is the best and fastest way to generate a visual snapshot of each component in React?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/), it's an open-source tool for developing UI components in isolation for React and other libraries and there is a lot of useful add ons which will help you during work process.

I have tried this for myself you can check it here [react-ui](https://hovakimyan.github.io/react-ui/?path=/story/atoms-button--sample)

If you want to have some page with a list of all components, you can create one story where you can show a list of all stories which you have in your project.